# Zoom in all content (not font only)

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website for visually impaired people. So there needs to be a button where they can increase font size.

Instead of only resizing my font, I want to zoom all the content. **Basically as you would get if you hit `cmd +` on your mac or `ctrl +` on windows, this way the page will be shown in mobile mode.**

Zoom didn't seem to do the trick.

Any way of achieving this?

Comment: you can try to scale the whole body element using the ```transform``` property

Comment: @fcalderan Tried that before, but doesn't work as expected.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: @MoshFeu Chrome

Comment: it's should works: http://jsbin.com/nategab/edit?html,css,output

Comment: @MoshFeu it scales, that's true. But my page doesn't goes to mobile view. It gets bigger and you need to scroll to see the content. 

But that's not what I want. I want the browser to jump to mobile mode.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If I surfing on desktop with 1920X1080 px screen  resolution to your site and click on some button, you want that I see your site as mobile?

Comment: @MoshFeu I want that the content is zoomed in like you would get when you hit cmd + on your mac. When you do that, all the content gets bigger and the websites switches to mobile version. 

This way everything stays nice (css wise) and your content is big enough for them to read.

Comment: That's good question. I'm not sure that it possible but good luck with that..

Comment: just let them use their own browser zoom controls (i.e. cmd-+ or ctrl-+).  You don't need to build it again.

Comment: @andi it's not my decision. So it will need to be done anyway.

Comment: Are you using rem/em values for your media queries?  So that when you increase the font-size, the media queries match differently.